# How to store class objects properly in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, list, class, indexing

I try simulating cell divisions, and I want to store cells which are part of cell lineages in a 2D array.
Thus the 2D arrays row elements are cells which are part of the lineages which have properties described in "Events" class.

Everything works fine, but at the end of my code, where I cannot store properly the class elements.

Please help, how can I store these values in Python3 efficiently.

Here is the class:

```py
class Events:

    # Initializer / Instance Attributes
    def __init__(self, level, cellNum, Type, time, timeStep, ID, gen, mutNum, childID):
        self.level = level
        self.cellNum = cellNum
        self.Type = Type
        self.time = time
        self.timeStep = timeStep
        self.ID = ID
        self.gen = gen
        self.mutNum = mutNum
        self.childID = childID
```

Here I store the leafs of the binary tree (cell division tree):

```py
Counter = 0
for i in range(N):
    for k in range(Counter,len(Data)):

        if int(Data[k][0]) == n:
            LeafArray.append(Events(Data[k][0],Data[k][1],Data[k][2],Data[k][3],Data[k][4],Data[k][5],k,0,0))   
            Counter = k+1
            break
```

Here I define the LinArray where I want to store the lineage data, and
I sort the lineages as the childID of a cell is the same as its child ID starting from a leaf node:

```py
LinArray = []

for i in range(len(LeafArray)):
    lincounter = 0
    LinArrayin = []
    LinArrayin.append(LeafArray[i])

    for j in reversed(range(len(EventVertices))):
        if EventVertices[j].childID==LinArrayin[lincounter].gen:
            lincounter+=1
            LinArrayin.append(EventVertices[j])

        if LinArrayin[lincounter].gen == 0:
            #print(lincounter)
            LinArray.append(LinArrayin)
            print (LinArray[0][1].gen) #error is here
            LinArrayin.clear()
            break
```

The strangest thing is when I get the error at highlighted line above,
which is an index error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HOT_LinTrace.py", line 131, in 
    print (LinArray[0][4].gen)
IndexError: list index out of range

It also return the proper value of that index.

Also it is strange that when I want to print out the stored elements of LinArray at the end of code, it does not return anything but the index error message.

Please help:)

Answer (score 0):

I finally could figure it out!

Python copied just the reference, and as I made LinArrayin = [], LinArray also got erased.

So if I change the line:
`LinArray.append(LinArrayin)`

to: 
`LinArray.append(LinArrayin.copy())`

it works:)

Hope it helps others as well...